# reporting services - sum tablix column values

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, reporting-services

I have many functions applied to rows in a tablix column. I need to sum all the rows in a tablix column. I am using reporting services 2005, so LOOKUP doesn't exist and I also do not have access to the SQL stored procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is rather vague, but I'll take a crack at the problem. Let's say that you have a textbox in the tablix column called Textbox5. In a footer row (either a group footer or the tablix footer), you can use an expression like this:

```
=Sum(ReportItems!Textbox5.Value)
```

That will sum up the values in that textbox after the functions have been resolved in each row.

Answer (score 0):

An aggregate function can be used only on report items placed in the Header or Footer.