# Can you sum a column in SSRS after all calculations are complete?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, business-intelligence

I have a column showing the results of a series of calculations made in SQL. The results can vary.

I would like to write a sum at the bottom of this column which is the sum of each row *after* all calculations have been been completed, i.e. resolved.

Currently I have written in the bottom row: [Sum(ColumnName)] and it sums data from my source dataset instead (not simply the rows in the tablix column)

I would like a function that simply looks at the rows and sums them (i.e. in this case the total at the bottom should be 18).

(it's a fluke that the total is currently 135, it's not a string concat)

[image: The last row is summing data from my returned dataset]

Comment: possible duplicate of [reporting services - sum tablix column values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418466/reporting-services-sum-tablix-column-values)

Comment: Can you clarify what expression you're using to bring out the 0's, 13 and 5 in the rows? I am confused as to how what you've already done is not working - to my knowledge if the 13 is as a result of the SQL query building the dataset, `[Sum(ColumnName)]` ought to treat it as 13...

Answer (score 1):

You should sum expressions instead of dataset fields.

Example:

If your column expression is `=Fields!ColumnName.Value - 1`

Your SubTotal expression should look like this `=Sum(Fields!ColumnName.Value - 1)`