# Sum/Running Total of Expression in a Group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have been racking my brains all day trying to research and figure out how to sum an expression in a group in a tablix.  Here is the basic setup:

I have a parent group called "Type", and within that is a child group called "CostCode".  I am hiding the details group underneath CostCode because it has individual transactions I don't need to see. So the visible data on the tablix is aggregated in the group header. In the CostCode group, I have a column with an expression that calculates a Projection figure for each header line of CostCodes using a group variable within the CostCode group.

In the Type group footer, I just want to calculate the sum of those projected figures like a subtotal.  However, the aggregation and the way I've done this is making it confusing to me. Does anyone know how to do this?

Attached is a picture example of what I have going on.  Again, just trying to sum the Projection column of which the values are from an expression:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked out this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418466/reporting-services-sum-tablix-column-values

Comment: I will check that out, thank you!

Comment: It feels silly to ask this, but can you do the sum just like you did for the Budget and Actual columns? Or are those values hard coded? The Cost/Hr column total looks wrong based on the other two.

Comment: I threw some numbers in for example purposes, so don't pay too much attention to the math. Each row in the Budget and Actual columns is a sum of the details group. The total at the bottom is the same expression but evaluates to its group. The Projection column, however, is from a longer equation that uses the values in the Budget and Actual rows.  When I try to sum it, I get this: The Value expression for textrun 'Textbox95.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' contains a variable reference in the argument to an aggregate function (or RunningValue).  Variable values cannot be used in aggregate functions.

Comment: @Jesse, I tried that method, but because I'm using an aggregate function in my Projections column, SSRS apparently won't let you do this unless you put the expression in a page header or footer.